# Practical interpretation of mean squared prediction error

Tags: regression, cross-validation, predictive-models, rms

I know that MPSE acts as a measurement of a model’s predictive abilities, but I have a hard time interpreting this situationally.

Say for example I develop a model for predicting a car’s resale price in dollars. I develop said model on training data and then validate on a validation set. I get a value of say 4000. I don’t know how to interpret this value then. I know it varies problem to problem as MPSE just like MSE is ‘good’ or ‘bad’ relative to the data itself. 4000 could be considered good if it the values were in the billions, or less so if it’s in tens of thousands.

Any input maybe explaining this example, or more in general of how to interpret MPSE is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

MSE or expected prediction error (EPE) are in the units (or units squared) of your target variable -- you should expect that it will be context-dependent. What may help is to look at the coefficient of variation (CV) of your predictions (or mean absolute percentage error [MAPE]):

$$CV = \frac{\sqrt{MSE}}{\bar{y}}$$

$$ \rm{MAPE} = \frac{100}{N}\sum_i^N \left|\frac{\hat{y_i} - y_i}{y_i}\right|$$

These measures take into account the general magnitude of the values you are trying to predict.

**Note**: Be careful if your $y_i$ are near zero for these relative measures...they can really ratchet up your errors. There are numerous "fixes" for this, for example [symmetric mean absolute percentage error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error) and [mean absolute scaled error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error)

Answer (score 0):

Since you understand the concept of a validation set. Let's say the true value at that point is 4,000, then the prediction error is zero. If the true value is 50,000 then the prediction error is 46,000.

You should know the true value because you are using a validation set.